# Math.Round Function in PCL

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I am converting my functionalities from the normal class library to PCL.
In the normal c# class library we can pass three parameters to the math.Round function to round a decimal number.
Previously we have  used the math.Round like following

```
Math.Round(value,digit, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) .
```

But in PCL I can see that “MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero” enumeration is not available.Can I do the same operation in PCL?

I am targetting my PCL to  ".Net framework 4.5","Xamarin.IOs" "Xmarain.Android" and Silverlight 5.Actually I dont need to support the PCl to silverlight 5.but I cant able to remove this silverlight 5 support.

Comment: Are you sure about that? MSDN lists it as available in PCLs.

Comment: Most likely, the PCL availability depends on which platforms you are targeting. As far as I can see, there are no `Math.Round` overloads containing a `MidpointRounding` argument in *Silverlight* or *Windows Phone* pre-8.0. If you are OK with targeting, say, *.NET Framework*, *Windows Store* and *Windows Phone 8*, you will probably be able to incorporate the `MidpointRounding` overload of `Math.Round` in your code.

Comment: Yes Anders Gustafsson.. I think so.I am targeting silverlight 5 also.But when i tried to remove the silverlight 5 ,it says it supports all of the other functionality like that.I laso selected "Xmarin.Android" ,xamarin.IOs" and dotnet framework 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design, it is Silverlight that's the hangup.  It belongs to the .NETCore subset, other frameworks like Phone7 and .NET Compact Framework are in that set.  Primary goal is to make the .NET install as compact as possible, for Silverlight getting the runtime downloaded in 10 seconds or less when a user visits a website that requires it, like Netflix, was a strong goal.  That of course can only work by subtracting out big chunks from both the CLR and the framework, the Math.Round() overload you want to use was chopped off to get there.

So what you see available in the PCL project is an automatic consequence.  It protects you from using classes and methods that are not available on one of the target platforms, and thus making your program fail, simply by hiding them.

You'll have to make-do with what you have available.  You'll get MidpointRounding.ToEven, the default.  A possible workaround is to multiply by a power of 10, add 0.5, round to 0 digits, then divide again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you checked it correctly? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx) it should be supported in PCL

under **Version Information** you can read

> Portable Class Library
>
> Supported in: Portable Class Library

otherwise there is a simple trick to achieve the same without any rounding functions, if you only need to round to integers and not specific decimal places:

```
roundedValue = (int)(valueToRound + 0.5)
```

if the value ends if `.5` or more it will summed to the next integer and the cast to `int` cuts off the decimal places. Otherwise for `.499..` and smaller values it won't be enough and again the cast to `int` cuts of the decimal places.

Comment: yes `0.7 + 0.5` is `1.2`; `1.2` casted to `int` is `1` but of course you can't round to different numbers of decimal places, only to integers

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this method is supported in PCL.

> .NET Framework
>
> Supported in: 4.5.1, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0
>
> .NET Framework Client Profile
>
> Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1
>
> **Portable Class Library**
>
> **Supported in: Portable Class Library**
>
> .NET for Windows Store apps
>
> Supported in: Windows 8

I created a small test project (PCL) and this works for me:

```
decimal d = Math.Round(0.555555M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```